# Почему при WAMP (ampps) выдает ошибку The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: apache, wamp

Установил WAMP (ampps). Решил протестировать его работу. Создал файл test.html, сохранил его в apache/htdocs, набираю в адресную строку следующий URL: `localhost/test.html`
Выводитcя ошибка 404:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что с этим делать?

Comment: Посмотреть в конфигах куда указывает DocumentRoot

Comment: @AntonShchyrov а как эта папка с конфигами называется?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov а вот, нашел в httpd.conf DocumentRoot

Comment: @AntonShchyrov написано: DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www"

Comment: @AntonShchyrov если переместить файлы в www, то всё работает)) Спасибо большое!)

Comment: @AntonShchyrov но как сделать так, чтобы всё работало, но при этом файлы были в другой папке. Мне хотелось бы, чтобы работало, например из C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/apache/htdocs. Я заменил Document Root на этот путь, но не заработало.

Comment: И перезапустить апач

Comment: @AntonShchyrov на странице выводится ошибка: Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /test.html on this server.

Comment: И настроить `<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov я не могу найти в этом файле <Directory "${SRVROOT}>

Comment: @AntonShchyrov или надо самому в этот файл внести эту строку?

Comment: Ищите, где определяются разные каталоги. И вам нужно скопировать определение для www в htdocs

Comment: @AntonShchyrov если хотите можете свой ответ написать именно как ответ, и я помечу как решение)